# mod_rewrite Fast and low resource way to block the request

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, request, block, drop

I use following rule to block requests based on some User Agents using modRewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(SCspider|PetalBot|ZyBorg).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(SCspider|PetalBot|ZyBorg).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

But I need to know if there is any better way (quick & fast) and less resource consumption to block/drop the requests
appreciate for any help

Comment: Which kind of user agents you want to block? could you please post some examples then we could help more, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I just need the the best part of blocking , not user agent identifing

Comment: I understand but which urls or bots you want to block? Or everything(any request) you want to block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples try following. Following should be faster than your tried one.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?:SCspider|PetalBot|ZyBorg) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

***Suggested improvements:***

- We need to use `.*` in condition part since anything that contains these strings should be blocked, you could change it to `\b(?:SCspider|PetalBot|ZyBorg)\b` to avoid partial matches too(just in case).
- Then you are creating capturing group in condition which is NOT required since its NOT being used anywhere later on.
- In RewriteRule portion also we need not to use `.*` we could simply use `^` to avoid matching everything, since we are anyway doing that match in Condition part.

Comment: Do you thin that RewriteRule ^ - [R=204] is faster and low resource base or RewriteRule ^ - [F,L] ? Thank you for explanations

Comment: @FarhadSakhaei, they are different, because `R=200` will give 200 ok result but `F` is forbidding the urls.

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong status code, it's 204 : no content

Comment: I need something like drop in modsecurity rather than block or deny

Comment: @FarhadSakhaei, oh ok no issues. IMHO `F` should be more faster than `R` because  that's kind of external redirection but haven't tested it.

Comment: @FarhadSakhaei, yeah, these rules should be Good, please test them out once and let me know if these help you.

Comment: I read somewhere which R = 204 is fast, But I'm not sure, just asked for that, I don't know how to benchmark something like that

Comment: @FarhadSakhaei, to be honest, if we correct and use Good regex(like I fixed most of it) then it shouldn't be too much difference IMHO, may be few milli seconds here and there, but if you keep these rules top of your htaccess file(no exceptions considering here) then these should be faster IMHO. Let me know your views on same, thank you.

Comment: @FarhadSakhaei, Also why I am saying using correct regex will help, since `.*` and creating capturing group will definitely take time because they will use memory to match and keep values safe in memory respectively.

Comment: Thank you for explanations, How can I chat with you?

Comment: @FarhadSakhaei, Is it apart from question or related to question, if related to question we could chat here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232244/discussion-between-farhad-sakhaei-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: Thank you it helped me, great regular expression explanation

Comment: @FarhadSakhaei, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.